# Recursion complexity

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

What will be the Big-O of the following code:

```
int f(int n)
{
int i, x;
if (n < 0)

return 1;
x = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)

x = x + i;
return x + f(n - 2);
}
```

I wonder how to write it in the standard T(n) form to use Master's theorem latter.
Will it be something like: T(n)=n/2T(n-2)?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so please use the `homework` tag.

Comment: No, it's not, I'm just trying to understand Big-O notation and I can't figure out what the complexity of this code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't mind what is there inside the function, first just see the recursive call...

a problem of size n has now become problem of size n/2.

now, how many times is this recursive function called? n times since the for loop inside the function runs for n times.

hence T(n) = n*T(n/2).

Answer (score 0):

The form is T(n) = (n+2)T(n-2) to be precise.

But for simplicity you can approximate it to T(n)= nT(n-2) as Big-O will depend on this term only

Comment: Why (n+2), could you explain? And what is Big-O?

Comment: You are iterating through the loop n times with additional 2 assignments